# Google analytics API sometimes return empty results

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, google-analytics-api

When using Google Analytics API (PHP Client library - as server to server service) many times it returns empty result set.
My code look like this:

```
public function getLeadDetails($view, $gauid, $lead_id,$refresh_token,$dates = [])
{
    Log::info("*****************GA Service - GAUID: ".$gauid." **********************************");
    $options['dimensions'] = implode(',',config('analytics.dimensions'));
    $options['filters'] = "ga:eventAction==".$gauid;
    $metrics = "ga:users";
    $view = "ga:".$view;
    $yesterday = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('yesterday'));
    $tomorrow = date("Y-m-d",strtotime('tomorrow'));
    if(count($dates)){
        $yesterday = $dates['yesterday'];
        $tomorrow = $dates['tomorrow'];
    }
    Log::info('GA_Service@getLeadDetails(), Request Params: ?ids='.$view.'&start-date='.$yesterday.'&end-date='.$tomorrow.'&metrics='.$metrics.'&dimensions='.$options['dimensions'].'&filters='.$options['filters']);
    try{
        $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
        $this->client->setAccessToken($refresh_token);
        $this->client->setClientId(config('analytics.client_id'));
        $this->client->setScopes([
            \Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS,
            \Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_EDIT,
        ]);
        $analytics = new \Google_Service_Analytics($this->client);
        $data = $analytics->data_ga->get($view,$yesterday,$tomorrow,$metrics,$options);
        if($data['totalResults'] && $data['totalResults'] > 0){
            Log::info('Inside GA_Service@getLeadDetails has totalResults');
            $rtn = [];
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($data['rows'] as $row) {
                $rtn['uacid'] = $gauid;
                $rtn['user_type'] = $row[0];
                $rtn['device_category'] = $row[1];
                $rtn['source'] = $row[2];
                $rtn['medium'] = $row[3];
                $rtn['campaign'] = $row[4];
                $rtn['ad_group'] = $row[5];
                $rtn['path'] = $row[6];
                $i++;
            }
            Log::info('Inside GA_Service@getLeadDetails lead '.$lead_id.' should be update');
            return $this->insertLeadDetails($rtn , $lead_id);
        }
        Log::info('GA_Service::getLeadDetails() returned empty results for lead: '.$lead_id);
        if(!count($dates)){
            $this->throwException('empty results for lead: '.$lead_id.' in GA_Service::getLeadDetails()',275);
            return false;
        }
        return 'empty results for lead: '.$lead_id.' in GA_Service::getLeadDetails()';
    }catch (\Google_Service_Exception $e){
        Log::info('Google service exception from GA_Service::getLeadDetails() - '. $e->getErrors()[0]['message']);
        $this->throwException($e->getErrors()[0]['message'], 335);
    }
    return false;
}
```

this function fire again every 5 minutes if the result was empty (5 times) and still misses some results.

any idea why and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you firing it every 5 minutes?

The data in the core reporting API isn't going to be stable for 24 - 48 hours. After that time it will never change so there will be no reason to request it again assuming you are saving it someplace.

[Data processing latency](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1070983?hl=en#DataProcessingLatency)

> Processing latency is 24-48 hours. Standard accounts that send more
>   than 200,000 sessions per day to Analytics will result in the reports
>   being refreshed only once a day. This can delay updates to reports and
>   metrics for up to two days. To restore intra-day processing, reduce
>   the number of sessions your account sends to < 200,000 per day. For
>   Premium accounts, this limit is extended to 2 billion hits per month.

So processing hasn't completed that is probably why sometimes you aren't seeing any data.

If you want real-time info you should be using the [real-time api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/).

Comment: Thanks mate, probably missed this part.